# Rails model with multiline home address best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

This is probably a simple/silly question, but is there a best practice around naming address attributes of a model?

Is the following ok or is there a standard way? Specifically, are the three address fields named ok?  How do you handle country/state vs. country/region?  And how about zipcode vs postalcode vs code?

```
t.string address1
t.string address2
t.string address3

t.string city
t.string country
t.string region
t.string state
t.string code?
t.string zipcode?
t.string postalcode?
```

Comment: If you want to be truly global you should add address4, prefecture, county, province and district at the least. I'm sure there are plenty more :) It's best to start with what is needed and grow.

Comment: What model are you building?

Comment: "Contact" or could be "Lead"